# jQuery Datatables adding a new row then setting attribute on that row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have written a logic that seemed to be working proper then recently a bug came up from it. What I am doing is allowing a user to add one or multiple rows to a data set. The data they add is passed to a AJAX post method where the posted data comes back with a set of data, that I append to the row that was just created in the form of hidden "data" attributes, and again this works to a point. However what I realized my problem is, is that these attributes are being added to the top row in the table rather than the newly created row, with that I am at a lost of how to get that last new row and append the attributes the way I want it to, the way it seems to be doing to the first row in the `tbody`.

So to quickly recap, the new row adds to the table properly, and is visually proper, and the attributes I want set in the form of `data` attributes work. However there is a mix match between what row they append to. With that my current code is:

```
taskmanagerExcludeTable.fnAddData([$('#source_filter_type option:selected').text(), jqVal, '<img src="/images/icons/png/light/recycle_bin.png" alt="Delete Exclude" class="datasource_exclude_delete" data-idr="reference">']);
var theNode = taskmanagerExcludeTable.fnSettings().aoData[0].nTr;
theNode.setAttribute('data-filter_id',obj.data.filter_id);
theNode.setAttribute('data-filter_type',params.filter_type);
theNode.setAttribute('data-task_id',params.task_id);
theNode.setAttribute('data-task_type',$('#source_filter_type option:selected').text());
```

I want to say that this line:

```
var theNode = taskmanagerExcludeTable.fnSettings().aoData[0].nTr;
```

More specifically `aoData[0]` is my problem. Since `0` is hardcoded into the method which means its assuming the first row. My question is how can I dynamically work with this so `0` isn't hardcoded and I can use some form of variable that gets the right index of the row being created?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to sit idle for long I started to think about my question and kept re-reading it. To finally have it dawn on me I should take a count of all the rows on the table in the tbody using `.length` and subtract `1` from it to match the indexing datatables keeps for management of the data for its own purposes, so what I ended up doing was taking a row count as a variable

ie:

```
var whichRow = $('#mytable tbody tr').length - 1;
var theNode = taskmanagerExcludeTable.fnSettings().aoData[whichRow].nTr;
```

and that solved my issue. Thanks for those who have viewed, considered helping, whatever. I have resolved the issue.